# Angular Routing, Different background Images for each route page

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I'm trying to set a different background image on the body of my separate partials.

But the images are just being loaded into the div area and not the whole body as i wanted, could any one of you be having an idea on how to solve this?

Here is my code

```js
angular.module('controller',[])

app.controller('AboutCtrl',['$scope', function($scope){
 $scope.title="The About page"
}])

app.controller('ServiceCtrl',['$scope', function($scope){
 $scope.title="Our services page"
}])
app.controller('ContactCtrl',['$scope', function($scope){
 $scope.title="How to contact us page"
}])
app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.bgimg = "img/home.jpg";
}])
```

```css
#bg {
  position: fixed; 
  top: -50%; 
  left: -50%; 
  width: 200%; 
  height: 200%;
}
#bg img {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  margin: auto; 
  min-width: 50%;
  min-height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<body >
<div  id="bg img" ng-controller="MyCtrl" style="background-image: url({{ bgimg }})">
 

 </div>
</body
```

Comment: 1.Add a controller like Session to body using ngController="sessionController as session" 
2. In the SessionController create a property called bgUrl. 
3. Inject SessionController or a SessionService allowing you to update bgUrl into each Controller where you  need background change.

Comment: I am quite at lost at injecting the session controller into each controller, would you be kind enough to give me a code snippet? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just move your main controller up to the body tag?

```
<body id="bg img" ng-controller="MyCtrl" style="background-image: url({{ bgimg }})">
  <div ng-controller="OtherCtrl">
```

Comment: Thanks Brian, but I already tried that, it wouldnt work, instead it displays a blank background..

Comment: It likely isn't working with the code you posted because you're keeping the bgimg variable in $rootScope but not accessing $root in your binding. Try `style="background-image: url({{ $root.bgimg }})"` instead.

Comment: Not sure what's up but [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/5IuYwA8jQUfVzDxxfPM9) is a plunker.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comments you create a service that holds the background variable. Then you create get/set methods to allow you to make changes.

```
var app = angular.module('controller',[])
  .service('SessionService', function(){
  var vm = this;
  this.bgImg = "https://c1.staticflickr.com/1/31/37271521_47df0e4547_b.jpg";
  return {
    setBgImg: function(newBgImg){
      vm.bgImg = newBgImg;
    },
    getBgImg: function(){
      return vm.bgImg;
    }
  }
})
```

Then you inject the SessionService into the Main controller you have set on Body. And call the get method to retrieve the background variable.

```
app.controller('SessionCtrl', ['$scope','SessionService',function($scope, SessionService) {
  this.getBgimg = SessionService.getBgImg;
}]);

<body id="bg img" ng-controller="SessionCtrl as vm" style="background-image: url({{ vm.getBgimg() }})">
```

Finally for every Controller you'd like to make the change, inject the service into the controller as well and call the Set method. In this example I have it being called from a button click function.

```
app.controller('ContactCtrl',['$scope','SessionService', function($scope,SessionService){
    $scope.ContactTitle="How to contact us page";
    $scope.winter = "";
    $scope.changeBg = function(){
      SessionService.setBgImg('http://alvaradoconsultinggroup.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/success.jpg');
    }
}]);

<div ng-controller="ContactCtrl">
      <p style="font-size: 25px;color: white;">{{ContactTitle}}</p>  
      <button ng-click="changeBg()">Change Back</button>
    </div>
```

I piggybacked off Brian Baker's plunker to show you the changes in action here.

https://plnkr.co/edit/RjgwdwuOFJgMct4y3qUS?p=preview

Comment: This gets back to the big question of when to use a service and when to use $rootScope. I agree that for most cases it's better to use a service to share data among controllers. For things like core app variables (as this seems to be) I think it's ok to just use $rootScope.

Comment: There certainly is more than one way to skin a cat. Injecting Services illustrates the dependencies required for the Controller which I consider cleaner code.